# Iterate with plyr::mapvalues

Tags: r, plyr, tidyr

I'd like to map multiple values from one dataframe to another. It's straightforward enough with one variable:

```
foods <- data.frame("name"=c("beef","soy","water","beef"))
data <- data.frame("name"=c("beef","soy","water"),"a"=c(1,2,3),"b"=c(4,5,6),"c"=c(0,0,0))
library(plyr)

foods$a <- mapvalues(foods$name, data$name, data$a)
```

But how can I iterate over multiple columns of the df "data" without rewriting the same line for each variable like this

```
foods$b <- mapvalues(foods$name, data$name, data$b)
```

A loop? sapply?

Comment: Try using `dplyr::left_join(foods, data)`.

Comment: Perfect! Simple syntax and blazing fast. Just what I needed!